# Disable services with preseed

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, apache-httpd, systemctl, preseed

I need to disable apache service with preseed file. Is there any options to run `systemctl disable` command with preseed?

Comment: In which distribution?

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done it by using late.sh

```
if dpkg -l | grep "apache"; then
        systemctl stop apache2.service
        systemctl disable apache2.service
fi
```